# Trigger a event when phone is shutdown?

Tags: android

Is there any way in which we can trigger events  when the battery is pulled or there is an unexpected shutdown ?
"android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN will give the desired result if shutdown is expected but what to do in other case.

Comment: `when the battery is pulled` ... No.

Comment: How is it possible to trigger event if there is no battery? Is your phone a ghost or somethng? :O :S

Comment: This is not possible. When the battery is pulled the phone is not aware of its power losw

Answer (score 1):

When the phone loses power it is not aware of this. The best you can hope for would be to save simple strings or ints using shard prefs. Have your app test to see if it was exited properly with a false boolean. If the user never finish the main activity the boolean will be false. If they did finish save it as true. If the app opens and its true make it false so you can start the cycle again.

Comment: The solution u refering is perfectly okay.but i want to detect that if by chance my phone is falling and accidentally battery comes out. so the alternative which i was thinking now is to detect the free falling and trigger a event on that momenteven if the battery is coming out or not. nothing best i can think of other than this